# How to change view in pycharm in SciView

Tags: python, pycharm, numpy-ndarray

I have an example to multiple each row and column and I am getting good results but I want to change view, when I multiply column I want to have result in n-columns in one row, and when I multiply rows I want to have one column and n-rows. Now it shows in both cases one row and multiple columns, and it is difficult to understand.

```
array2 = np.array([[2,3,5,1],
      [5,1,2,8],
      [5,1,6,-1]])
multiply_columns_array2 = array2.prod(axis=0)
multiply_rows_array2  = array2.prod(axis=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reshape](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) or [vstack](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).
The best way in my experience is to use `reshape(-1, 1)` because you don't have to specify the size of the array. It works like this:

```
>>> a=np.arange(1,4)
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.reshape(3,1)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
>>> np.vstack(a)
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Also, you can use [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) in order to reshape your array:

```
In [32]: a = np.arange(10)
In [33]: a
Out[33]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [34]: a[:,None]
Out[34]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])
```